# Kotlin - Persist MutableList on SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, kotlin, persistence, mutable

I've been playing around with Kotlin for Android. I have a mutable list which is a list of objects. Now I want to persist them, but I don't know what's the best way to do it. I think it can be done with SharedPreferences but I don't know how to parse the objects to a plain format or something. The objects are actually coming from a data class, maybe that can be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very easy to persist any data within SharedPreferences. All you need to do is get **Gson** `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'` and then create class you would like to persist like this:

```
class UserProfile {

    @SerializedName("name") var name: String = ""
    @SerializedName("email") var email: String = ""
    @SerializedName("age") var age: Int = 10

}
```

and finally in your SharedPreferences

```
fun saveUserProfile(userProfile: UserProfile?) {
            val serializedUser = gson.toJson(userProfile)
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString(USER_PROFILE, serializedUser).apply()
        }


fun readUserProfile(): UserProfile? {
            val serializedUser = sharedPreferences.getString(USER_PROFILE, null)
            return gson.fromJson(serializedUser, UserProfile::class.java)
        }
```

Comment: In that case is it better not to use a Data Class, am I right?

Comment: well, you can use `data class` in kotlin with default values, but i find it good practice to keep it this way. it is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Firebase too for data persistence, you can use SharedPreferences, but personally I find it more easy and comfortable using Firebase.
I will leave a link here so you can take a look at disk persistence behavior of [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities). 
Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks I thought about that solition but I needed something local

Answer (score 1):

For lists it think using sqlite will provide you with better control of your data.
Check out [anko's sqlite wiki](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-SQLite) for more info.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preferences are mostly used in storing data like settings or configs, it's not meant for storing large data though it can do it as long as you implement `Parcable`. If you think your data contained in your `MutableList` is large, best way is to make a database.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use this **Kotlin** extension functions to store and edit your list to SharedPreferences. I think they are realy useful.

```
inline fun <reified T> SharedPreferences.addItemToList(spListKey: String, item: T) {
    val savedList = getList<T>(spListKey).toMutableList()
    savedList.add(item)
    val listJson = Gson().toJson(savedList)
    edit { putString(spListKey, listJson) }
}

inline fun <reified T> SharedPreferences.removeItemFromList(spListKey: String, item: T) {
    val savedList = getList<T>(spListKey).toMutableList()
    savedList.remove(item)
    val listJson = Gson().toJson(savedList)
    edit {
        putString(spListKey, listJson)
    }
}

fun <T> SharedPreferences.putList(spListKey: String, list: List<T>) {
    val listJson = Gson().toJson(list)
    edit {
        putString(spListKey, listJson)
    }
}

inline fun <reified T> SharedPreferences.getList(spListKey: String): List<T> {
    val listJson = getString(spListKey, "")
    if (!listJson.isNullOrBlank()) {
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(listJson, type)
    }
    return listOf()
}
```